# Adding TextView for each item in array

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to split sqlite column into an array and then add a `TextView` for each item of the array.  Below is my function to add a `TextView` for each item in array:

```
private void BuildTable() {

    sqlcon.open();
    Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();

    int rows = c.getCount();
    int cols = c.getColumnCount();
    String[] array;
    c.moveToFirst();

    // outer for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // inner for loop
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
            array = c.getString(1).split(",");
            for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                tv.setText(array[k]);
               row.addView(tv);

           }

        }

        c.moveToNext();

        table_layout.addView(row);

    }
    sqlcon.close();
}
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.logquiz.thequiz.logquiz/com.logquiz.thequiz.logquiz.RulesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Why not just use a `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is on the inner for loop

```
for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        tv.setText(array[k]);
        row.addView(tv);
}
```

here you are adding the same `TextView` multiple  to the same row instance, and this is not allowed. Change your code like

```
for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        tv.append(array[k]);
}
row.addView(tv);
```

this way every TextView is added at most once to the current row

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the correct solution is even a bit more drastic than Blackbelt suggested. The following snippet actually creates a new TextView for every line of text:

```
   // inner for loop
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

      array = c.getString(1).split(",");
      for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
        tv.setText(array[k]);
        row.addView(tv);

      }
    }
```

The problem is identified correctly by Blackbelt: you are trying to reuse the same TextView instead of creating a new one each time.